# DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValuePath in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a combo box in data grid, fill it from database using access. I set this column selected value path and display member path in WPF?

Comment: What's your question / problem *exactly*?

Comment: I add a combobox in datagrid and i made a class that has property of name and id. I make a list of class object and fill it from database. My question is, i want to set itemsource, displaymemberpath and selectedvaluepath to this column

Comment: It helps to show to code to start with, and tell what you've tried. Adding a question mark to a sentence is not the same as asking a question

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the combobox from the column's element style and the element editing style for setting the items source property.
Example:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMainGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Student List" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding StudentsList}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding StudentsList}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Relationships between classes:

```
class SampleEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now, then = DateTime.Now;

    #region Constructor

    public SampleEntity()
    {            
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<StudentEntity> StudentsList { get; set; }

    public StudentEntity SelectedStudent { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Notify Property Changed

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    #endregion
}

class StudentEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now, then = DateTime.Now;

    #region Constructor

    public StudentEntity()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Notify Property Changed

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: studentslist that is the name of the list? But datagrid.itemssource  is list

Comment: Your DataGrid will have an ItemsSource which is a list of some type of class. You need to have the list of your combobox ItemsSource type inside that class. My StudentsList is List<StudentEntity> inside a SampleEntity class and List<SampleEntity> is the ItemsSource of datagrid bound in code behind. Adding the code of the relationship for better understanding, please check the edited answer.