# Several combo boxes in one DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind combobox with different values in each row to DataGrid. My problem is most likely that I do not know how to set `ItemsSource` and `SelectedValuePath`. How should it be done?

.cs:

```
    private List<List<ComboItem>> ComboBoxItemsList = new List<List<ComboItem>>();
    ...
    foreach (AppSettingsElement list in enablers[key])
    {   
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] lines = list.Comment.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<ComboItem0> comboItems = GetComboItemList(lines);
        // clean comment
        list.Comment = lines[1];
        //add to comboList
        appSettingsComboBoxList.Add(new AppSettingsElement {Comment=list.Comment, Name= list.Name, Value=list.Value, ComboItems = comboItems });
    }
    AppSettingsDropDowns.ItemsSource = appSettingsComboBoxList;

    ...
    public class ComboItem0
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }    
    }
    public class AppSettingsElement : ComboItem0
    {
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<ComboItem0> ComboItems { get; set; }
}
```

.xaml:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="AppSettingsDropDowns" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="8" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Element Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Text" Header="Value" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:** My code currently displays blank selection of combo boxes.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228984/datagridcomboboxcolumn-selectedvaluepath-in-wpf/49229495#49229495

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar So my problem is basically that I do not bind and send list<> from ``comboItem`` to the ``comboBox``? Also, you helped me quite a lot with a few things I did not managed to implement yet, but I'll send ~50 points by the end of this week

Comment: Your problem here is that - DataGrid's items source will be a collection/list of some class type. That particular class type needs to  have properties which will be the items source of your comboboxes an they will also be a collection/list. So the parent should have collections of all the comboboxes that you need to show on the UI. Just like in my example I have a List<StudentEntity> this is for one combobox column only, if you need more you will need more such properties for each of the column specifying their items source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="AppSettingsDropDowns" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="8" CanUserAddRows="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Element Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="ID"  Header="Value" Width="*" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />                                
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```